# Scaling an image doesn't work as expected?

Tags: javascript, html, css, transform

I'm scaling an image down using the `scale` transform. That's working fine, except that the original image size is used to calculate the page size so I get horizontal/vertical scrolls in a huge empty page. I am a bit confused on how this works, isn't the scale supposed to reduce/enlarge the image?

Can I somehow get rid of the "extra" space not used? I don't need a CSS only solution, using javascript here is perfectly fine.

Fiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/kcYCm/

**EDIT**

@jgv solution posted below does size the image properly, but it doesn't solve the issue with scaling.

If we try using that approach, and instead try to scale the image up we get a funny effect. It zooms in only in part of the image and the scrollbars are displayed again. So when the image is scaled down it doesn't affect the other but when it's scaled up it does? Is this expected?

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/kcYCm/6/

Comment: Do you have specific dimensions for the desired final size of the image? I would just get rid of the `scale()` CSS function and set a specific `width` to the element, ensuring it to be resized properly: http://jsfiddle.net/kcYCm/3/

Comment: Not an option. I need to take a huge image, any size, and scale it down, so it can be scaled up later on. It's supposed to run on mobile devices so I'm pretty much stuck with `transforms`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try wrapping the image in a div and specifying the dimensions of the wrapper. No CSS3 but it works.

```
<div style="height: 300px">
  <img src="http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/4/4e/Les_Invalides_de_Paris_ceiling_huge.jpg" style="max-height: 100%; max-width: 100%"/>
</div>
```

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/kcYCm/5/

Comment: This does solve the problem, I got there before posting but I was looking for something that could fix it after using the scale. If I can't find a solution for that I'll have to work around with this. Thanks!

Comment: @caiocpricci2 For the future "zoom" or "upscale" events, you could find a workaround with some easy JavaScript fiddling with this given solution.

Comment: @jgv I've made a major change on the question, I guess it explains better what the problem is! I've gave it another try using the wrapper  but it behaves funny if I try to scale it up.

Comment: @caiocpricci2 did you try scaling the wrapper instead of the image?